# Mac OSX Mavericks - ZSH can't 'source ~/.zshrc', too many open files

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal, zsh

I can't source any changes to my .zshrc (or my .bash_profile for that matter), because I get this error when I try:

```
/Users/ME/.zshrc:source:100: too many open files: /Users/ME/.zshrc
```

I've tried `ulimit -n 10000`, but it doesn't work. I've also tried adding a launchd.conf file (there wasn't one there, I had to create it) to permanently change the hard & soft file limit, but on reboot, my terminal instantly crashes with a `Process Completed` message. (deleting the launchd.conf file & rebooting fixes this issue).

This could be related: for some reason, my `$PATH` variable is extremely long, as in thousands of characters. There are many repeating parts, for example, here is part of what I get if I do an `echo $PATH` :

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin........
```

That continues hundreds of times.

This made me think something in MAMP is rewriting my $PATH variable over and over which is causing all my other problems, but I can't find where its happening, and I don't know how to fix it.

Has anyone run into this before??

Comment: also, check your `~/.zshrc` and, if you're using `oh-my-zsh`, anything in your `.oh-my-zsh` directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

To find what's broken in your PATH variable, on Mavericks, you can need to check those files:

```bash
cat /etc/paths
```

```
ls -l /etc/paths.d/
```

(I bet that you will find something about MAMP!)

I would move everything out from `/etc/paths.d/` to somewhere safe, reboot, and see if that helps.

If it does (as you can have paths in other places as well) - post files from `/etc/paths.d/` related "MAMP" and we will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Ten-year-old question, but these symptoms are easy to reproduce with this in ~/.zshrc:

```shell
path+=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin
source ~/.zshrc
```

Which suggests that something in the chain of startup files is sourcing one of the startup files.