# OSX Mavericks .zshrc cannot source

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to source my zshrc. It sources fine when before I add this line:

`. ~/Dropbox/configs/aliases`

Then I get this:

```
/Users/mkrell/.zshrc:.:13: too many open files: Dropbox/configs/aliases
/Users/mkrell/.zshrc:source:53: too many open files: /Users/mkrell/.zshrc`
```

My `$PATH` variable is `/Users/mkrell/bin:/usr/local/bin:` repeated over and over again.

I attempted the advice of moving everything out of `/etc/paths.d/` to my Desktop, as said in this thread:

[Mac OSX Mavericks - ZSH can't 'source ~/.zshrc', too many open files](https://superuser.com/questions/690206/mac-osx-mavericks-zsh-cant-source-zshrc-too-many-open-files)

and restarting. No change whatsover.

This started to happen after I ran BundleInstall on [this](https://gist.github.com/iammerrick/9676071) guy's .vimrc

Immediately after this iTerm2 would always give me the error message

```
A session ended very soon after starting. Check that the command in profile "New Profile" is correct.
```

and close immediately. I would change the profile and it would still do this.

To solve this, I moved `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist to ~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist2`and that solved it, but then I got the behavior I described originally.

I have deleted every .vim file and reinstalled .oh-my-zsh but I am no nearer the solution.

Comment: What's in ~/Dropbox/configs/aliases? Specifically, does it do anything that'll source ~/.zshrc? This sounds like an infinite source recursion to me...

Comment: Ohh, I think your right!

    `# source
    alias source="source ~/.zshrc" `

There's a bunch of other stuff to but this might be it.

Comment: YAY! That did it! Deleted that line and all is working! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! **I <3 Stack Exchange!**

Comment: Since your problem was solved, can you close the question, please?

Comment: @MarlonRichert Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those coming here from Google; the answer was that I was sourcing my `.zshrc` file from another included file. This issue is called infinite source recursion.